# Why is $E(f(X,Y)|\mathcal{F}_t)=\int f(x,Y)P^{X|\mathcal{F}_t}(dx)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_t, P)$ and with notation (regular conditional probabiltiy assumed): $$P^{X|\mathcal{F}_t}(B)=P(X\in B|\mathcal{F}_t)=E(1_B(X)|\mathcal{F}_t),$$  how can I prove that for a real-valued measurable function $f$ and a $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable random variable $Y$ we have:$$E(f(X,Y)|\mathcal{F}_t)=\int f(x,Y)P^{X|\mathcal{F}_t}(dx)?$$

**My attempt**

I think one could approach by first showing it for indicators and than working one's way up. But what would the indicator in this case look like (in the $2$-dim case)?

Answer (score 1):

$$E[f(X,Y)|\mathcal{F}_t]=\int f(X,Y)dP_{\Omega /\mathcal{F}_t}=\int f(x,y)dP_{X\circ Y/\mathcal{F}_t}=\int f(x,Y)dP_{X/\mathcal{F}_t}$$
Since, being $Y$ $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable:
$$P_{X\circ Y/\mathcal{F}_t}(A\times B)=I_B(Y)P_{X/\mathcal{F}_t}(A)$$

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by $P_{\Omega/\mathcal{F}_t}$?

Comment: $P_{\Omega /\mathcal{F}_t}(\mathcal{A})=P[\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{F}_t]$